# BaseCommandModule class could not be found, contrary to the correct namespace being used

Tags: c#, class, compiler-errors, namespaces, dsharp+

As of creating this first attempt of a bot, it seems I've found myself trying to figure this one out for a while. That being, I'm getting the usual compiling error for an unknown class in an unused namespace for a class whose namespace I am in fact using, which contrary to the official documentation should be `DSharpPlus.CommandsNext`. But in this case that is not the deal, `BaseCommandModule` seemingly does not appear to be an existing class in the namespace it's supposed to be apart of.

It appears other source code that I found uses the same namespace and class without a problem so at this point I'm stumped. Any idea of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using the prerelease version 4.0.0. Check the `include prerelease` box on the top left to be able to update to it, or if you're using command line, `dotnet add package DSharpPlus --version 4.0.0-rc2`. Note that the rc3 version will be coming out very soon, and it will go out of prerelease in the near future as well.